# How to re-initialize DataTable in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have a requirement in which I have to store the state of the **DataTable** like *'pagination', 'sorting', 'search'* etc. For this I have set the '**bStateSave**' property to '**True**' and this is working pretty well. I know that 'bStateSave' save the state in the form of **Cookie**. Now I have another requirement in which I have to reset the **DataTable** and reinitialize it in case of User Login.

**ForEx:**

```
if (sessionUserLogin == 'True') {
       $('#myTableId').dataTable({ "bStateSave": false, "bDestroy": true});            
       $('#myTableId').dataTable({ "bStateSave": true });
  }
   else {
         $("#myTableId").dataTable({ "bStateSave": true });
  }
```

As per above example the "**sessionUserLogin**" tells if the user login into the system, if this flag(**sessionUserLogin**) sets to True, I want to **Destroy** the previous state and **initialize** the table again so that it can continue saving the state. Else condition is used to handle the other postbacks in the system as after login of the user I want to maintain the state of the table even after the **postbacks** like any **DropDown** change or **Saving** the records.

My above code works fine when the user login, I am able to clear the state of the table, but I am not able to initialize the table state again.

I have gone through this [URL](http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.4/DataTable.defaults.html#fnStateSave). But still not able to find the solution.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8154/bstatesave-cookie-when-does-this-reset

Comment: I already view this link but in this link "iCookieDuration" property is used which sets the expiration time of the cookie but as per my requirement I want to delete the cookie in case of user login and wants to reset it again.

Comment: The (7th) reply from user "bennybenben" shows a solution without messing with the cookie.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the code posted by "bennybenben" but I am unable to understand the code, can you please post an answer and help me in the implementation of my code using "bennybenben" posted code. Thanks.

Comment: Check the documentation for `state...`-functions such as [`stateLoadCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback). These should help accomplishing your request - at least if you're using the latest version of dataTables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using its `destroy` method as below

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
if (sessionUserLogin == 'True') {
        table.destroy();
        $('#YourTableID').empty();
        $('#YourTableID').DataTable( {
             "bStateSave": true
        });
  }
   else {
         $("#YourTableID").DataTable({ "bStateSave": true });
  }
```

**EDIT**

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
if (sessionUserLogin == 'True') {
        table.destroy();
        $('#YourTableID').empty();
        table = $('#YourTableID').DataTable( {
             "bStateSave": true
        });
  }
   else {
         table = $('#YourTableID').DataTable( {
             "bStateSave": true
        });
  }
```

Comment: First I want to confirm that "#myTable" = "#YourTableID" If YES then it is giving me pop-up "DataTables warning (table id = 'myTableId'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable." Also it is not working as per my requirement.

Comment: Yes!! It's same ID's!! I'll edit my answer!! Check and let me know!! Bdw what version of dataTable you are using??

Comment: I used your edited answer, now when the user login the state is clear means I am able to see the default state like pagination: 10 though it disturbed my table width but that's ok I will handle it. But now when I changed the pagination from default: 10 to 25 and do any postback like dropdown change the code will move in the else condition of your code and it's not able to maintain the state now. Are we missing something.

Comment: I am using version: 1.9.4 of datatable.

Comment: instead of `bStateSave` try using `stateSave: true` and let me know!! may be it's not saving the state now!!

Comment: May I know what is that `sessionUserLogin` and how you are assigning and initializing it??

Comment: `sessionUserLogin` tells us that the user is login into the system. I set the value of this session at the the time of the login. Its because I have to clear all the previous state of the datatable and assign a new state. n else condition user comes if he do any other postbacks like dropdown change etc.

Comment: Is it possible to create any fiddle or any sort of example thing online regarding what you are trying to do!!

Comment: I debug my jquery code and found that destroy() method throw the code on the starting point where I dynamically binding my table. I am binding my table inside the `div` from the ajax request here I first make the `div` empty like  `$("#div").empty()`. Destroy method throw at this point which menas it never calls the below code that we write below the detroy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to sort this out by using the below code, you can place the common functions outside the conditions:

```
if (sessionUserLogin == 'True') {
                    function save_dt_view(oSettings, oData) {
                        localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData));
                    }
                    function load_dt_view(oSettings) {
                        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname));
                    }
                    function reset_dt_view() {
                        localStorage.removeItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname);
                    }
                    reset_dt_view();
                    $('#myTableId').dataTable({
                        "bStateSave": true,
                        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) { save_dt_view(oSettings, oData); },
                        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) { return load_dt_view(oSettings); }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    function save_dt_view(oSettings, oData) {
                        localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData));
                    }
                    function load_dt_view(oSettings) {
                        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname));
                    }
                    function reset_dt_view() {
                        localStorage.removeItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname);
                    }
                    $('#myTableId').dataTable({
                        "bStateSave": true,
                        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) { save_dt_view(oSettings, oData); },
                        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) { return load_dt_view(oSettings); }
                    });
                }
```